# Problem with Flutter accessing REST API on device

Tags: api, rest, flutter

My Flutter application accesses a REST API on my web site. When I run with the local emulator it works 100%, but when I use it with the device (Samsung A80 cell phone using Android) or install the apk on the phone, access to the database does not work.

Is there a configuration missing?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mysongs_v2">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
</manifest>
```

The error does not appear to be the access to the database, but it only happens when I use the cell phone.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is when I run using the emulator.

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting on the debug console?

Comment: I attached the images to the post.

Comment: I verified that the error is not accessing the database.

Comment: I believe the problem is the location's JSON.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!!! It worked on the emulator because Android is in English. It didn't work on the cell phone because Androi is in Portuguese. The error was in the JSON file of the Portuguese language. Thanks for your attention

Comment: Glad it worked out in the end. :)